# What is the relation between message passing and probabilities in Bayesian inference?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian-network, belief-propagation

The belief propagation algorithm is a message passing algorithm that can be used to estimate marginal probabilities on Bayesian networks.

What is the definition of these messages? What is the relation between the messages and the marginal probability of a random variable? How come that we can retrieve marginal probabilities from an iterative procedure that passes messages between nodes?

Comment: Message passing is a way to eliminate variables. Please refer to this note: https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/inference/jt/

Comment: Then I thought this would be of help: https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/inference/ve/